# Lua: ProteaAudio API confuse -- How to use it?

Tags: api, audio, lua

Hello everyone.

Sorry for my noob question as I'm just a non-programmer trying to learn to program with Lua.

I'm so attracted with Lua since it's indeed very simple, either in size as well as in syntax.

And I decided to explore further experiment with this Brazilian born language, like playing with sound -- as I did in Python and Ruby.

So I found this ProteaAudio and tried to play the sample scripts came within package I downloaded from [here](http://viremo.eludi.net/proteaAudio/index.html).

The package comes with two sample scripts:

1. first named **example.lua** to play the ogg sample file (also comes within the package)
2. and another to play function generated sound named **scale.lua**

The first script runs just fine on my Win 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 x86 machine.

But the second script only runs on Windows and got an error when I tried to run it on Ubuntu, generating this message:

> ../lua52: scale.lua:13: bad argument #1 to 'soundLoop' (number expected, got nil)
>
> stack traceback:
>
> [C]: in function 'soundLoop'
>
> scale.lua:13: in function 'playNote'
>
> scale.lua:29: in main chunk
>
> [C]: in ?

The full original source-code from **scale.lua** is:

```
-- function creating a sine wave sample:
function sampleSine(freq, duration, sampleRate)
    local data = { }
    for i = 1,duration*sampleRate do
        data[i] = math.sin( (i*freq/sampleRate)*math.pi*2)
    end
    return proAudio.sampleFromMemory(data, sampleRate)
end

-- plays a sample shifted by a number of halftones for a definable period of time
function playNote(sample, pitch, duration, volumeL, volumeR, disparity)
    local scale = 2^(pitch/12)
    local sound = proAudio.soundLoop(sample, volumeL, volumeR, disparity, scale)
    proAudio.sleep(duration)
    proAudio.soundStop(sound)
end


-- create an audio device using default parameters and exit in case of errors
require("proAudioRt")
if not proAudio.create() then os.exit(1) end

-- generate a sample:
local sample = sampleSine(440, 0.5, 88200)

-- play scale (a major):
local duration = 0.5
for i,note in ipairs({ 0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12 }) do
    playNote(sample, note, duration)
end

-- cleanup
proAudio.destroy()
```

And since I got confused with this ProteaAudio Lua API, I really can't get why this error comes.

Please help.

Comment: Try this before the `for` loop: `print( sample, type(sample) )`

Comment: While typing up my answer, I forgot to mention that I took the liberty of adding the full original source-code for `scale.lua` to your question, both for future reference AND to try get some more attention to your excellent question.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually just a guess, but...

To play a "major" scale upwards (8 notes, jumping: *full full* half, *full full full* half) the original code does:

```
local duration = 0.5
for i,note in ipairs({ 0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12 }) do
    playNote(sample, note, duration)
end
```

where the `sample` is a handle to a pre-generated sample created by `proAudio.sampleFromMemory` which is returned by function `sampleSine`, that passed it a calculated 'table' representing a 440hz sine-wave (concert-pitch frequency for note 'A4', the first above middle 'C').
Thus playing an 'A major scale' by changing (increasing) the 'pich' (frequency) of that sample (in 8 steps=notes). That pitch-calculation is done by function `playNote`.

Function `playNote` accepts the following arguments:
`sample, pitch, duration, volumeL, volumeR, disparity`,
*but* it currently does *not receive* the arguments:
`volumeL, volumeR, disparity` (which will then be `nil`).

So when function `playNote` tries to call:
`proAudio.soundLoop(sample, volumeL, volumeR, disparity, scale)`,
then the call will end up like:
`proAudio.soundLoop(sample, nil, nil, nil, scale)`,
where the `sample` is passed on and `scale` is the 'playback-pitch' of that sample, as just calculated (according to specified `note`) by function playNote.

Your error-message states: `bad argument #1 to 'soundLoop' (number expected, got nil)`.
***Hmm, that seems consistent with what is happening*** (assuming that 'bad argument #1' is the second argument, in this case `volumeL`).

So,
you might want to **try** specifying some values for `volumeL, volumeR, disparity` like:

```
local duration = 0.5
local volumeL = 1.0
local volumeR = 1.0
local disparity = 0.0
for i,note in ipairs({ 0, 2, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 12 }) do
    playNote(sample, note, duration, volumeL, volumeR, disparity)
end
```

From the [proteaAudio documentation](http://viremo.eludi.net/proteaAudio/class_device_audio_sdl.html) one can read about `soundLoop`'s arguments:

```
sample    -            A sample handle returned by a previous load() call
volumeL   - (optional) Left volume
volumeR   - (optional) Right volume
disparity - (optional) Time difference between left and right channel in seconds. 
                       Use negative values to specify a delay for the left 
                       channel, positive for the right.
pitch     - (optional) Pitch factor for playback. 0.5 corresponds to one octave 
                       below, 2.0 to one above the original sample.
```

If that should do the trick, then the arguments might not be so optional on Ubuntu.

Hope this helps!